# Android Studio (Log Sensor Data to csv. File)

Tags: java, android, csv

I have to log my Sensor data from my Android Phone to a csv. file so I can use it further , the problem is I tried something with some code(FileWriter to csv) that I found and put it into my code and it does not work, can maybe someone tell me what I do wrong, where my error is. The idea is to just record different sensor data with different EventHandlers like in the Code Example and then write the sensor data to a csv. file together and that csv. file should be on the phone.

I have maybe to mention that I have never before programed in Java or did Android , so please try to answer me as simple as possible, thank you :)

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView txt_currentAccel, txt_prevAccel, txt_acceleration, txt_temp;
    ProgressBar prog_shakeMeter;
    Switch switch1;

    //define Sensor Variables
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;

    private SensorManager mSensorManagerNew;
    private Sensor mTemp;

    private double accelerationCurrentValue;
    private double accelerationPreviousValue;


    private int SwitchFlag = 0;

    final String TAG = "SensorLog";
    FileWriter writer;


    private SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER && SwitchFlag == 1) {
                float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
                float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
                float z = sensorEvent.values[2];

                accelerationCurrentValue = Math.sqrt((x * x + y * y + z * z));
                double changeInAcceleration = Math.abs(accelerationCurrentValue - accelerationPreviousValue);

                accelerationPreviousValue = accelerationCurrentValue;

                //update text views
                txt_currentAccel.setText("Current =" + accelerationCurrentValue);
                txt_prevAccel.setText(("Prev = " + accelerationPreviousValue));
                txt_acceleration.setText("Acceleration change =" + changeInAcceleration);
                prog_shakeMeter.setProgress((int) changeInAcceleration);


                try {
                    writer.write(String.format("ACC; %f; %f; %f; %f; %f; %f\n", sensorEvent.values[0], sensorEvent.values[1], sensorEvent.values[2], 0.f, 0.f, 0.f));
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

        }
    };
    private SensorEventListener sensorEventListenerNew = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            float temp = sensorEvent.values[0];
            txt_temp.setText("Temp = " + temp);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt_acceleration = findViewById(R.id.txt_accel);
        txt_prevAccel = findViewById(R.id.txt_prevAccel);
        txt_currentAccel = findViewById(R.id.txt_currentAccel);
        txt_temp = findViewById(R.id.txt_temp);

        prog_shakeMeter = findViewById(R.id.prog_shakeMeter);

        switch1 = findViewById(R.id.switch1);

        // Initialize Sensors
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        mSensorManagerNew = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mTemp = mSensorManagerNew.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);


        switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b == true) {
                    SwitchFlag = 1;
                } else {
                    SwitchFlag = 0;
                }

            }
        });


    }

    public void flag() {
        if (SwitchFlag == 1) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Writing to " + getStorageDir());
            try {
                writer = new FileWriter(new File(getStorageDir(), "sensors_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".csv"));
            } catch (
                    IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListenerNew, mTemp, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener);
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListenerNew);


    }


    private String getStorageDir() {
        return this.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
    }
}
```

Comment: You never invoke `flag()` which would in theory open the file for writing - seems like your intent would be to invoke `flag()` in the `onCheckedChanged` callback after setting your boolean.  The problem with that is your sensors may already be producing data and attempting to write (using a null `writer`) so you will need to either a) verify file is open before writing or b) open the file by default before registering the sensor listeners or c) register the listeners (and unregister) when open or closing the file.